# Docker Compose - Flyway - Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, flyway

I'm traying to deploy a microserivice and a flyway service with Docker Compose in Ubuntu. The docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '2'

services:

mysqldb:
image: mysql:5.6.26
environment:
  MYSQL_USER: user
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
  MYSQL_DATABASE: base
ports:
  - "3306:3306"

flyway-service-i:
image: mialk/flyway-service
volumes:
 - "../resources/db/migration:/migrations/ro"
depends_on:
 - mysqldb
links:
 - mysqldb
command: migrate -url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/base -user=user -password=password -baselineOnMigrate=true -    locations='filesystem:/migrations'

  service1:
image: my/service
ports:
  - "8080:8080"
links:
 - mysqldb
environment:
  - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/base
  - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=user
  - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=password
```

But when I run the command: sudo docker-compose up, I have this message:

**flyway-service-i_1  | ERROR: Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource (jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/base) for user 'user': Host *'172.18.0.4'* is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server**

Each time that I run the command, I get a different host, e.g:

**ERROR: Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource (jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/base) for user 'user': Host *'172.18.0.6'* is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server**

The data base was created in that way:

```
CREATE DATABASE base CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON base.* To 'user'@'localhost';
```

The ifconfig command shows that Docker has the IP 172.17.0.1.

I don't know why flyway can't connect to the data base, and why the host changes en each call,can you help me please?

**Thanks! :)**

Comment: What version of docker are you using?
`$ docker version`

Comment: @Fabian I'm using :
 Version:      1.12.1
 API version:  1.24

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue

In this line
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON base.* To 'user'@'localhost';`
you grant priviledges to user on `localhost` but your `service1` and `flyaway-service-1` services are running in their own separate containers and therefore are not running on `localhost` (with respect to the `mysqldb` container). If these services were running *inside* the `mysqldb` container then maybe they could be running on `localhost`.

#### Possible Resolution?

You may want to try using the hostname of the services/containers you're granting access to instead of `localhost`?

ie : 
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON base.* To 'user'@'service1';`

#### Docker Networks instead of Container Links

Also, I would suggest using Docker's new networking feature instead of the legacy container linking method. See [rationale behind docker compose "links" order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902051/rationale-behind-docker-compose-links-order/39903214#39903214)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Fabian!

But, if I ran     
    GRANT ALL ON base.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password', it would able to connect, woulnd't it?

Thanks!